# Нужна помощь по иконкам

Tags: html, css

Пишу мобильную версию сайта и столкнулся с проблемой:

Почему иконки на телефонном браузере отображаются не чётко, а на ПК браузере чётко? Как это исправить? Может что-то нужно в `head` прописать?

Comment: А можно по-подробней?
Ссылку или код показать

Comment: возможно вы некорректно сжимаете иконки через стили в css. т.е не пропорционально уменьшаете

Comment: Нет картинка не была сжата !

Comment: Вами, может, и не была сжата. А телефонным браузером была.

Comment: Ну я заменил иконки  на SVG то все ок стало !

Comment: Так на телефонах ретина, надо картинки 2х+ делать, если растровые. Свг конечно лучше ;)